# Combined in/out audio with one 3.5mm 4 pin jack - Macbook Pro (2015)

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, microphone

I recently bought a 3.5mm 4 Pin to 2x 3 Pin 3.5mm headset splitter adapter. Like this one: [Headset splitter on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004SP0WAQ/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B004SP0WAQ&linkCode=as2&tag=2046it09-21).

When I plug headphones jack and microphone jack into the splitter and splitter into my macbook pro 13" (2015) it only recognizes a new output audio device. But in sound preferences in input tab is only one input device - Internal microphone, type: Built-In.

Actually I think it worked fine for the first time I've connected it, but after some restart or disconnecting the splitter, it never worked as it should.

Any ideas or similar experiences?

Comment: I just bought a cheap able planet Stereo Headphone with boom microphone and am in the same situation. The system won't recognize the microphone but all iOS devices work fine with the mic. I'll let you know if I can get it working this weekend with some combination of cables, adapters and/or software setting changes.

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching this type of connection set-up and came upon this page.  I saw a few people mention (I think in the Amazon reviews) that you have to connect the adapter to the headset first before connecting it to the phone, that for some reason it mattered which thing got plugged in first... that to not try to understand it, it was just an "Apple thing".  Hope it's helpful.